# using ilaplace in conjunction with rltool

Tags: matlab

Using Matlab, I have the following code:

```
s = tf('s')
K=0.5;
H= 1/(s*(s+2));
Hcl=feedback(K*H,1)
ilaplace(Hcl)
rltool(H)
```

I want to get the inverse laplace transform of the unity closed-loop system.
rltool(H) generates automatically the unity closed-loop system. That's why I pass the open-loop system as an argument.

When I run this code, Matlab gives an error about ilaplace:

"Check for incorrect argument data type or missing argument in call to function 'ilaplace'."

Can someone help me how to use ilaplace and rltool concurrently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for this problem.

```
syms s;
K=1/2;
H= 1/(s*(s+2))
Hcl=simplify(K*H/(1+K*H))
P=poles(Hcl)
ilaplace(Hcl)
H = syms2tf(Hcl)
rltool(H)
```

`ilaplace` works with symbolic expressions and not with a transfer function. By converting the symbolic expression to a transfer function midway of the code, I can use both functions in the same code.

Notice I've added the function `simplify` and changed the beginning from `s=tf('s')` to `syms s`

The function `syms2tf()` can be found [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27302-syms-to-tf-conversion?s_tid=answers_rc2-2_p5_BOTH)